# invalid key format for git access ssh-add on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I am trying to configure git with ssh access so on my ubuntu virtual machine I generated a key pair.
 as per instructions here https://linuxtechlab.com/how-to-install-github-on-ubuntu-step-by-step/

`$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C “your_email@youremail.com”`
the key I have generated is following
user_rsa

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
nY6auyJS1pmqLyAl6tRu4EstZHxqQwAAAAMBAAEAAAGAfINVuhW9Rp5JAwzppNZ8FfmvM4
K8UTqx91auY6tg0EwlcufCJUhhRGF7qzkk/lzEVrwHRhZhAEEQZ8jH1sjq0ra+D+TLdFfZ
mtr3Qy5I6QPvByqa70Ui93/X/EKHPfH9o4itL+iQheg/H8aZxZw2dP4nePJgjAaCwGZNqn
+PlIAvvDAt71t9K2fyDObX4TXikhezAAAAwQDBsrclMLbe6cwSpDWEOIaTNLiuVtbdXMm9
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and another key is user_rsa.pub

```
ssh-rsa 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 username@gmail.com
```

I try to add both keys the private key is added

```
debian@osboxes:~/git_keys$ ssh-add ./user_rsa
```

for public key I get error 
    debian@osboxes:~/git_keys$ ssh-add ./user_rsa.pub 
    Error loading key "./user_rsa.pub": invalid format

what should I do now to configure ssh access. Is adding public key required or not?

```
debian@osboxes:~/git_keys$ ssh-add user_rsa.pub 
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0755 for 'user_rsa.pub' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
```

I had changed the permissions also for user_rsa.pub to 600 but I still get the error

```
debian@osboxes:~/git_keys$ ssh-add ./user_rsa.pub 
Error loading key "./user_rsa.pub": invalid format
```

I am not able to understand what to do now from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to load the public key into `ssh-add`; it does that automatically when you add the corresponding private key.